Shouldn't adding an exogenous variable change my forecast?
After i derive statistical correlations between market variables and the business segment I'm interested in forecasting... i load a number of variables and the selected segment in 1 dataframe and then split it into 2 (training/testing)... future variable values are known through an external source, future segment values are 0... this is a univariate forecast model... all data is quarterly.
df_full_temp = df_NVARS_Seg_Full.loc[:, included_vars + ['segment_code']]
df_full_temp = np.log(df_full_temp + 1)
df_train = df_full_temp[df_full_temp['segment_code'] != 0]
df_future = df_full_temp[df_full_temp['segment_code'] == 0]

fitting the model with or without exogenous values... the forecast is barely changing, even if I manually divide future exogenous variables by half, forecast is almost unchanged.
model = SARIMAX(df_train['segment_code'], exog=df_train[final_vars], order=(1,0,1), seasonal_order=(0,1,1,4, trend='ct')

model_forecast = results.forecast(steps=20, exog=df_future[final_vars]).rename('segment_code') 


Is there a way to make the model give more significance to those exog variables?
Hyperparameter tuning: I tried autoarima in addition to a loop to find min AIC/BIC but nothing yielded a good forecast... any advice here? note: sometimes fitting the model with the result from performing the loop search for best AIC/BIC... creates an exponential forecast, extremely unreal.

I tried to manually change exogenous future values and refitting model but results didn't change.

To #1, my gut is that your model may be telling you the exog variables aren't all that significant when it comes to finding patterns and trends for forecasting purposes. I suppose it could be that whatever variation you're expecting to see because of your exog variable is better represented by another variable(s). That raises the question of whether forcing additional significance would yield a more accurate forecast. If the answer is yes, then the best approach may be to add an adjustment factor on the back end of the calculation based on whatever significance you think it should have.

try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for the stats nerds...
